# Vimeo API: need to set vimeo video mode HD using Vimeo API

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm using vimeo API's and showing all videos from my vimeo account on my site. Problem is that I'm not found any setting to show videos in `HD mode`. 
I'm using vimeo video url in `iframe` and my code is that:

```
<iframe id="video_play" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $video_id; ?>?api=1&player_id=video_play&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Can anyone help me to show vimeo video in HD mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the settings for your video:

https://vimeo.com/(your_video_id)/settings

Then go to Embed, there is an option at the bottom under "Miscellaneous" where you can tick for "Default this video to HD when embedded":

[image: Default this video to HD when embedded]

Comment: Cool. When you get time if you could mark it as a solution that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

when you embedded this link
https://api.vimeo.com/videos/123556 
with your html page then vimeo will automatically provide a video player with sd/hd/uhd configuration

Comment: Please add some explanation and don't only post a link